# IIS application Pools

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6

I have one application "App1" under IIS. Inside "App1" I have another application called "App2", in IIS. They both have web.configs and each needs to read their own.

On one server configuration this is not an issue. On another, it didn't like the fact that the connection string values are in both files.

Would this indicate that the "App1" web.config is first?

Our server guys say that the configuration is the same. Has anyone see this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the values in web.config like this are inherited. appSettings and connectionStrings are two such areas where values are inherited.

There is a syntax to remove inherited settings before adding new ones. That should be done in your connectionStrings section, to avoid collisions on what i assume are conn strings with the same name.

```
<remove name="connstringname"/>
<add name="connstringname" ... />
```